# Customize permission in permission page

Tags: users

I want to have multiple roles in my site :
FirstOne is Admin :
 Admin is not super admin `(user 1)` but Admin can define permission for other users .
Permission is controlled by Super Admin .
i want to show some of the permission options in the `admin/people/permissions` not all of them for this role.

Any idea ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using any of these modules :

1. [User Protect](https://www.drupal.org/project/userprotect)

> This module allows fine-grained access control of user administrators,
>   by providing various editing protection for users. The protections can
>   be specific to a user, or applied to all users in a role.

2. [Role Deligation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation)

> This module allows site administrators to grant some roles the
>   authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the
>   administer permissions permission.

3. [Administer Users by Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole)

> This module allows site builders to set up fine-grained permissions
>   for allowing "sub-admin" users to edit and delete other users — more
>   specific than Drupal Core's all-or-nothing 'administer users'
>   permission. It also provides and enforces a 'create users' permission.

Comment: Ya Sure @Soheil. I think Role Deligation can definitely solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to check [Permissions Lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_lock) module.

Feature Set.

> 1. Remove a configurable set of permissions/roles in the permissions
>      administration table for users in roles that you want to give the
>      'administer permissions' permission, but don't trust completely with
>      that power.
> 2. Integrates with User Permissions module
> 3. Provides a hook_permissions_lock() to define locked permissions / role from within your (custom) module. This makes it
>      easier to
>      deploy / repeat permissions_lock module settings